# Discord.js failing to execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I ran the example code from the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/), with my bots token, and it fails to execute with this error:

```
(node:9880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AbortError: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/pi/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:107:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9880) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have recieved this error on my rpi *and* my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was being caused by a slow connection, and discord.js would timeout. This was solved by a faster connection and a remote host

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3471#issuecomment-531651223) github comment, it seems that this is caused by requests taking too long to resolve, and Discord.js simply aborts it to avoid getting stuck.

If this causes an issue by causing your bot to go offline, you can add the following line to catch all unhandled promise rejections in your code:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", error => console.error("Promise rejection:", error);
```

This not only will stop your bot from crashing, but will also provide more detailed error information, which you can further investigate [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#how-to-diagnose-api-errors).

Comment: I tried that and recieved a new error:
Promise rejection: { AbortError: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/pi/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:107:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'AbortError',
  code: 500,
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot' }

Comment: @IanSwift And to be clear, you're trying to run the example code provided on the Discord.js homepage?

Comment: yes, I am trying to run the code provided on the Discord.js homepage

Comment: @IanSwift Running the example code with my bot token works fine for me. Perhaps it's an issue with your bot token?

Comment: I ran discord.io bots with that token and they worked fine. Could a slow network connection be my issue?